# BreadCrumb trail MVC3 and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Anyone have an example of how to create a breadcrumb trail using the latest MVC3 release and razor syntax?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Try narrowing down by providing more details.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to achieve this by using the MVC SiteMap Provider: http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/.  It contains features to create breadcrumb trails, and is documented fairly well (and you can always grab the code and modify it to do exactly what you want.)

Comment: The MvcSiteMap provider doesn't work with MVC3 and Razor...Or, at least I couldn't get it to work and many others online couldn't either.

Comment: You might want to get the latest from source.  I'm fairly positive it works with MVC3.  As for not working with Razor, I'm not sure why it wouldn't... It just uses HtmlHelpers, which should be ViewEngine independent.  Do you know what parts are not working?

Comment: If not, then I do not know of any other libraries out there to do what you want.  You may just have to code it yourself.

Comment: I got the latest and compiled it against .NET 4.  No errors but when I tried to use it I got a bunch of errors...I know that isn't much help but I have since removed it from the project and I don't know the exact errors.  I guess I'll readd it and step through and see what I get.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help, hope you get it figured out.  Maybe someone else will come along that's done this before and be able to help you out.

Answer (score 6):

To get the MvcSitemapProvider working do the following:

In your `.sitemap` file change:

```
<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-2.0" />
```

to:

```
<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up writing my own simple sitemap provider.  It's just based on URLs just like the ASP.NET standard sitemap.  It works because the site is really simple but has lots of static files.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Mesoboard project's source code in ASP.NET MVC3 w/Razor:

http://mesoboard.codeplex.com/

The project implements a breadcrum mechanism among other things.